# How to query a text field in postgresql remotely with ssh?

Tags: postgresql

If I do:

```
ssh -t remote_server "cd /; sudo -u postgres psql -c 'SELECT rolname FROM pg_roles WHERE rolname = 'username';'"
```

It returns an error:

```
ERROR:  column "username" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT rolname FROM pg_roles WHERE rolname = username;
```

It seems that the `"'"` before `'username'` closes the `"'"` after `psql -c`. Would like to know how to solve this.

Answer (score 2):

I got the answer with some help of friends:

ssh -t remote_server "cd /; sudo -u postgres psql -c 'SELECT rolname FROM pg_roles WHERE rolname = '\''username'\'';'"

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
ssh -t remote_server 'cd /; sudo -u postgres psql -c "SELECT rolname FROM pg_roles WHERE rolname = '"'"'username'"'"';"'
```

Multiple levels of quotes are a pain in shell.